# Pandas: Return part of the day from datetime column directly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

Hi all is it possible to get part of the day (morning, noon, afternoon, ...) directly from datetime column in a dataframe using Pandas?
For example for day of the week it's possible to do:

```
df['weekday']= df.date.dt.day_name()
```

and it returns: Monday, Tuesday, ...
Is there something similar available in Pandas for part of the day? For example:

```
df['part of day']= df.date.dt.day_part()
```

Notice: I am not looking for an answer like this link which you write the function yourself:
[Get part of day (morning, afternoon, evening, night) in Python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571311/get-part-of-day-morning-afternoon-evening-night-in-python-dataframe)

Comment: So you are looking for day name (Monday, Tues etc ) and part of the day Morning/ afternoon / Evening as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571311/get-part-of-day-morning-afternoon-evening-night-in-python-dataframe

Comment: @instinct246 I gave day name as an example. I know how to get it. I want to know if you can get part of the day as well

Comment: @DvirCohen I know about that solution, one can always write functions, I wanted to know if there is something in Pandas